# Best-fit for 3D Vision questions

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

Where is the best Stack Exchange site for questions about theoretical 3D Computer Vision concepts? Something like "Stereo-Vision", "Structured-Light" "Triangulation" ...

Examples:

*These are imaginary questions. They may be stupid.*

1. What is gain of using 2 cameras with structured light since 3D-Reconstruction could be done from one camera and projector?
2. 2 Cameras aligned horizontally are very suitable for solving triangulation problem. So, why some devices make them crossing?
3. What the problems in 3D-reconstruction that by adding a third camera can be solved?

Comment: Depends on the question

Comment: Edited with questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Computer Science Website](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> ....
>
> This site covers theoretical and applied computer science at any
> level, including but not limited to:
>
> - ....
> - **vision, graphics**

It seems that answered my question.